# C# how to add a percentage if you get the total sum of a column(listview)

Tags: c#

I'm creating a POS (Point of Sale) system. In order to get the total amount of orders the cashiers need to click the listview column.

Here's my code:

```
private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
    int value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        value += int.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[e.Column].Text);
    }

    total.Text = Convert.ToString(value);
}
```

I want to add `12%` VAT to the `total` if the column is clicked. What should I do?

Comment: `total = sum * 1.12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this.

```
total.Text = Convert.ToString(value * 1.12);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much ! :') can you up this post?
I want to share this answer for those newbie like me in c# :) ! 
Thankyou again have a nice day, you're amazing.

Comment: i would mark this if it's not prohibited, it says that i can accept an answer in 5 minutes. Thank you sir.

Comment: @empoyasilo This was more of a maths than programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following before setting total.Text.

```
value += value * 0.12
```